# How to add multiple events for “input” in post messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, postmessage

I have simple input and HTML5 video player with iframe, I want to add multiple events to input with post message.

Problem.

1. I want `on input focus event` it should play video1 if user delay typing it should play video 2 if the user is still delaying it should play video 3.
2. Assume user start typing then it should play video 4 so this will be `on keyup` event.

so here is my solution I have so far .

HTML formpage.html:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <iframe id="videoframe" src="videoframe.html"></iframe>


    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" />

</div>
```

Here is videoframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wideo iframe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="videowrapper">
        <video  id="playervideo" controls></video>
        <canvas id="videocanvas" width="1024" height="576"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/videoframe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Here is videofrme.js

```
   // creating stage variables for animation

   var timeline = null;
   var autoplay = true;

   var movieName1 = 'https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4'
   var movieName2 = 'https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005610.mp4'
   var movieName3 = 'https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4'
   var movieCzekanie ='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005612.mp4'

   function resizeFunction() {
       $("#videowrapper").height($("#videowrapper").width() * 576 / 1024);

   }

   window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
   function receiveMessage(eventPosted) {
       var values = eventPosted.data.split("&");
       var event = values[0].split("=")[1];
       var fieldtype = values[1].split("=")[1];
       var value = values[2].split("=")[1];

       console.log(event, fieldtype, value);

       switch (event) {
           case "fieldchanged":

               switch (fieldtype) {
                   case "name":

                       openSlide("nameSlide", {
                           value: value
                       });

                   default:
                       break;
               }
               break;
           default:
               console.log("Event not supported");
               break;
       }

   }

   function openSlide(slideName, params) {
       switch (slideName) {
               case "nameSlide":
               openName(params);
               break;
       }

   }

   var params = null;

   function openName(_params) {
    playVideo(movieName1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        playVideo(movieName2)
    }, 8000);

   setTimeout(function(){
       playVideo(movieName3)
     }, 9000);

     setTimeout(function(){
        playVideo(movieCzekanie)
      }, 3000);
      $(input)

   }

   function openNazwisko(_params) {
    playVideo(movieNazwisko1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        playVideo(movieNazwisko2)
    }, 3000);

   setTimeout(function(){
       playVideo(movieNazwisko3)
     }, 6000);


   }

   function playVideo(src) {
       $("#playervideo").attr("src", src);
       $("#playervideo")[0].muted = false;

       if (autoplay == true) {

           var playPromise = $("#playervideo")[0].play();

           if (playPromise !== undefined) {

               playPromise.then(function () {}).catch(function () {

                   if (autoplay == true) {
                       $("#video-unmute-button").addClass("show");
                       $("#playervideo")[0].muted = true;
                       var playPromise2 = $("#playervideo")[0].play();

                       playPromise2.then(function () {

                       }).catch(function () {
                           $("#video-start-button").addClass("show");
                           $("#video-start-button").on("click", function () {
                               $("#playervideo")[0].muted = false;
                               $("#playervideo")[0].play();
                               $("#video-start-button").removeClass("show");

                           });
                       });

                       console.log("pause force");
                   } else {

                   }
               });
           } else {}
       } else {

       }

   }
```

Here there is form.js which have an event with post messages

```
//form script

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(resizeIframe);
            $(window).resize();
            $("input#name").on("focus", function () {
                document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage( "event=fieldchanged&fieldtype=" + "name" + "&value=" + $("input#name").val(), "*");
            });
             $("input#name").on("keyup", function () {
                 document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage( "event=fieldchanged&fieldtype=" + "name" + "&value=" + $("input#name").val(), "*");
            });

        });

        function resizeIframe() {
            console.log($("iframe#videoframe").width()*576/1024 );
            $("iframe#videoframe").height( $("iframe#videoframe").width()*576/1024 );

        }
```

Here is demo I am doing [multiple events on one input](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/rvBpcmWV65LOM2ls?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

So I have managed to solve the first problem using `on focus event` and `setTimeOut function`.

Now am struggling to add an event when the user starts typing this will be the second event `on keyup` so that when a user starts typing it should trigger this event using post message the same as I did with on focus.

what do I need to add to make it work as I want? any help, any idea will be appreciated. thanks

HAPPY HOLIDAY's TO ALL !!!

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing jQuery with Vanilla JS? I do not see an issue with your `.on()` functions. Are you seeing any errors or alerts in Console? maybe add `console.log` to the callback and make sure it's getting executed.

Comment: Hii, there no reason but am just trying to solve the issue, there is no error whatsoever, but am not getting the result I want,

Comment: Am unable to get your plunker working.

Comment: me too, but in my localhost, everything works fine its just simple HTML js code, I just copied to plunker from my desktop,  that is all I have in my desktop, I tried debugging on that plunker no errors if u can just copy to the desktop it should work, as u can see even CSS is not loading there . :(

Comment: Will test some more in a bit.

Comment: Am getting two errors: `TypeError: "dew$3 is not a function"` and `Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: "dew$3 is not a function"`

Comment: If you `postMessage` on each `keyup` event the video will reload with every keystroke, that is bad UX, @user9964622

Comment: your right now I solved  the issue but as u said it will reload with everykeystroke, do u know what event can solve this issue, so that the video will not realod at each key stroke.?

Answer (score 0):

I was able toget your Plunker to work: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Pm4vWqp4n4kKIq5H?preview=formpage.html

Make sure to Preview the formpage.html as the index.html is not where this issue lays. Here are the changes I would suggest for your form.js file:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(resizeIframe);
    $(window).resize();
    $('#name').on('focus', function() {
        $('#videoframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(
            'event=fieldchanged&fieldtype=name&value=' + $('#name').val(),
            '*'
        );
    });
    $('#name').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#videoframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(
            'event=fieldchanged&fieldtype=name&value=' + $('input#name').val(),
            '*'
        );
    });
});

function resizeIframe() {
    console.log(($('iframe#videoframe').width() * 576) / 1024);
    $('iframe#videoframe').height(
        ($('iframe#videoframe').width() * 576) / 1024
    );
}
```

This appears to do what you wanted, when it got focus, it started playing. When I pressed a key, it started playing again at the new header.

If it were me, I would consider JSON format. This way you can create objects or arrays of the events and actions and then stringify them for the post message.

When I review videoframe.js, I cannot determine where `$(input)` is defined. This ends up throwing an error in console on `keyup`.

If this is not working as expected, then please clarify what should be happening. Be precise. Walk us through all the steps.

Comment: Hii Twisty thanks  for help, your changes does not do anything , because in videoframe.js I used to play video based on time . on input focus event it should play video1 if user delay typing it should play video 2 if the user is still delaying it should play video 3. this is okay.  but the fourth video should only be played when user start typing anything.  right now the fourth video is played after 6 seconds chek this function `setTimeout(function(){
        playVideo(movieCzekanie)
      }, 6000);`
        in videoframe.js

Comment: I have solved the issue by changing the following `"event=fieldchanged&fieldtype="`   to `"event=ontyping&fieldtype="` now works as I want but as twisty pointed that this will be bad  UX on each keyup event the video will reload with every keystroke, so now I am trying to figure out how can I solve this issue :)